# Error with templated function overloading and out of class definition

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, overloading

I am learning about game development and in the book i need to overload a function with a template. original function is

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename)
{}
```

and the overloaded version is

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
template <typename Parameter>
void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename, const Parameter& secondParam)
{}
```

When I try to run the code in main with this

```
ResourceHolder<sf::Texture, Textures::ID> textures;
```

i get the compilation error:

> ```
> error: prototype for ‘void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier, const string&, const Parameter&)’ does not match any in class ‘ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>’
> void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename, const Parameter& secondParam)
> ```

How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Did you remember to declare the new function template in your class?

Comment: ` void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);

  template <typename Parameter>
  void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);
`
I have these inside my class declaration. I am using .hpp file for decleration and .inl for definition if it makes a difference.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "specialize" not "overload".  Regardless, please post an [mcve]

Comment: Guillaume Racicots solution worked. I had missing parameter in my overloaded function. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the declaration in your class:

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
struct ResourceHolder {
    // ...

    // member function must be in the class
    template<typename Parameter>
    void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename, const Parameter& secondParam);
};
```

Comment: ` void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename); template <typename Parameter> void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename); ` I have these inside my class declaration. I am using .hpp file for decleration and .inl for definition if it makes a difference.

Comment: Then I don't know how to reproduce the issue. Here's a godbolt of my solution working: https://godbolt.org/z/pnK-bN

Comment: Ah thank you, I was missing the "const Parameter& secondParam" from my overloaded function. Solved.